# install IIS 7 on win 7

Tags: iis

I have downloaded IIS 7 when i clicked install this messege appear

```
The IIS Management Console is not installed, but it is required for managing remote IIS servers. Please install it before installing IIS7 Manager. Do this by going to - 
Control Panel / Turn windows features on and off and then select the IIS Management Console in the Inet . . . .
```

I searched on google and it said that `You will need to make sure IIS Management Console is checked, and it will install it for you when you check it`, but I had not installed IIS before  . How to fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS is a Windows Component. It is not something that you can download.

Have a look at this answer on super user: https://superuser.com/questions/288312/where-can-i-find-iis-in-windows-7