# couldn't find the internet information services in windows features

Tags: windows, iis

I am trying to install the IIS on windows 7 ultimate, the following links guide how to install 
[install IIS 7 on win 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482756/install-iis-7-on-win-7) and
https://superuser.com/questions/288312/where-can-i-find-iis-in-windows-7

but, I couldn't able to find the Internet Information services node in windows features,[image]

can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure IIS is in every 'type' of windows 7 nor how many types they have: Server, Enterprise, Pro, Normal, Crippled, Crap, ...

Comment: is there any software / update, I can download from microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You should try reinstalling windows and see if that fixes it, since IIS should be there.

Comment: do I only reinstall on existing, or a new installation?

Comment: You should try a new installation, wiping everything and starting over